# Set Mac to wake and run scripts while in sleep mode

Tags: automator, sleep-wake, python, automation, development

I'm a Python developer and I would like the Mac to awaken from sleep when I configure it to do so and run some scripts or certain programs during the day. On Windows there's "Task Scheduler" [enter link description here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=x7aD2YFOMbE) that does it just great: the PC wakes on its own and runs programs. I heard about the "Mac automator" and I don't think it has the availability to wake the Mac from sleep to run programs.

Answer (score 1):

## pmset

Use the built-in command line tool [`pmset`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) to schedule a Mac to wake or power on. From the `pmset` manual page:

> Schedules the system to automatically wake from sleep on July 4, 2016, at 8PM.
>
> ```
> pmset schedule wake "07/04/16 20:00:00"
> ```
>
> Schedules a repeating shutdown to occur each day, Tuesday through Saturday, at 11AM.
>
> ```
> pmset repeat shutdown TWRFS 11:00:00
> ```

### `caffeinate` After Waking

Be aware that when waking, your Mac will return to sleep as soon as possible. macOS is looking for user activity to justify the wake or a power assertion.

Any script or tool you run after wake must register a power assertion to stop macOS returning to sleep. Create the assertion with [`caffeinate`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate/):

> ```
> caffeinate −i make
> ```
>
> `caffeinate` forks a process, execs "`make`" in it, and holds an assertion that prevents idle sleep as long as that process is running.

### Third Party

Alternatively, tools like [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) exist:

[image: DssW Power Manager for macOS]

I am an engineer involved with Power Manager; feel free to get in touch and ask technical questions about how it works.